# C#: String to Class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to initialize a Generic List object from Type name having as String like below:

```
List<(Type.GetType("CustomClass"))> AvroList = new List<(Type.GetType("CustomClass"))>();
```

What is the correct way to do it?
Question Update:
Also I need like below which is a statement with error

```
var AvroList = GetList<Type.GetType("CustomClass")>();
```

GetList has some logic which returns the list.

```
List<T> GetList<T>()
{
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make the enclosing method generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `MakeGenericType` method and then use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of your generic type:

```
var type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("CustomClass"));

var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Since you don't now the type at compile time, casting `IList` is best thing  you can do.You can also use *dynamic* but it is not safe either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there way to use LINQ with this?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson yes it is possible but not easy. You have to get correct overload of each linq method you wanna use (with reflection), then create generic methods using `MakeGenericMethod`, pass the type instance. Then call the `Invoke` method(s)  pass list instance...

Comment: Holy crap... I think I'd just stay with `foreach` code unless I head a really compelling reason.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson it doesn't matter actually, if you don't know the compile-time type you can't take advantage of type-safety with foreach either...

Comment: @Selman22 Still easier to check if `obj is MyClass` and perform whatever logic you need with it within the loop.

Comment: You can also use [`Enumarable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx) or [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406.aspx) (extension) methods (regarding your last comment).